# 'undefined' is not a function - Jasmine unit test for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I can't figure out why I keep getting this exception. The service is in one module, and the helper (unit under test) is in another. I'm trying to mock out the service (which is a dependency for the helper) and create the helper injecting that mocked service.

Thanks for any ideas!

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'jasmine.spyOn(myService, 'someData')')

Here's the test:

```
describe('myHelper test', function () {
var myHelper, myService;
var expectedData = 'test';

beforeEach(module('serviceModule'));
beforeEach(module('helperModule'));

    it('works', function() {

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.service('myService', function() {
                someData = jasmine.spyOn(myService, 'someData').and.callFake(function(){
                   return 100; });
            });
        });

        var mockMyService;

        inject(function(myService){
            mockMyService = myService;
        });

        angular.module('helperModule').config(['myHelperProvider', function (myHelperProvider) {
            return myHelper(mockMyService, _);
        }]);

        expect(myHelper.someData()).toEqual(expectedData);
    });
```

});

Comment: Having trouble following your unit test code out of context - can you post the service/helper module code as well?  In general, my suggestion would be to make a formal mock of the service rather than doing it in the unit test itself since that makes the mock portable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `spyOn` then you should inject the real service inside the test and then do a `spyOn`.

```
 inject(function(myService){
            jasmine.spyOn(myService, 'someData').and.callFake(function(){
                   return 100; });
            });
            mockMyService = myService;
        });
```

Currently you are trying to create a mock service `myService` by injecting original service `myService` (which also has bug, because you have not done injection of original service)!